Why am I getting a code 400 from Spotify?
I am trying to get the access token from spotify, but it returns a bad request. I don't understand what could be causing it.
async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {
    const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    params.append("code", code);
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
    params.append("code_verifier", verifier);

    const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: params
    });
    
    
    const { access_token } = await result.json();
    return access_token;
}

the clientId, code, and verifier are all there, so I don't know what is wrong.

What information, if any, appears in the body of the Bad Request message?

POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token 400 (Bad Request)
thats all it says

Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
true
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
false
redirected
:
false
status
:
400
statusText
:
""
type
:
"cors"
url
:
"https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

Perhaps you did the previous step incorrectly

Based on the code you have provided and matching it with the numerous available auth flows on the Spotify API guide, I see that you are following the PKCE authorization flow.
Now, in the documentation, the code_verifier key's value sent in the payload of the POST request is retrieved from the local storage key code_verifier. But in your code above, the value is being retrieved from local storage key verifier (see line 2 of your code above). So perhaps this could be the reason for the API response of bad request.

I dont think that is the problem, as earlier in my code I set the key to verifier:
localStorage.setItem("verifier", verifier);
